# Why doesn't the UFO touch the flatbed rock at the bottom of the scene? Why does it stop before?

Tags: racket

This is my program

```
; constants
(define SCENE-WIDTH 200)
(define SCENE-HEIGHT 200)
(define BGR-COLOR "blue")

(define FLAT-ROCKBED (rectangle 100 10 "solid" "black"))

(define MTSCN (place-image FLAT-ROCKBED
                           (/ SCENE-WIDTH 2) SCENE-HEIGHT
                           (empty-scene SCENE-WIDTH SCENE-HEIGHT   BGR-COLOR)))

[define UFO
  [overlay [circle 10 "solid" "green"]
           [rectangle 40 4 "solid" "green"]]]

(define X-POS (/ SCENE-WIDTH 2))

(define UFO-PADDING
  (- SCENE-HEIGHT 
     (/ (image-height UFO) 2)
     (image-height FLAT-ROCKBED))) 

; functions
[define [ufo-landing height]
  [cond
    [[<= height UFO-PADDING]
     (place-image UFO X-POS height MTSCN)]
    [[> height UFO-PADDING]
     (place-image UFO X-POS UFO-PADDING MTSCN)]]]
```

It is from the first chapter of the [How to Design Programs, 2nd Edition](http://www.ccs.neu.edu/home/matthias/HtDP2e/part_prologue.html).

When I call the `(animate ufo-landing)` function in the interactions area this is the output I get [image]

The UFO does not touch the flatbed rock.
How do I make it do that?

**Edit 1**:
The ordinate for placing `UFO` on the scene is dependent on two factors.

1. The height of the `FLATBED-ROCK` over which it has to land so that the `UFO` just touches its surface.
2. The center of `UFO`; its placement takes up 10 px above and below its center coordinate since its height is 20 px.

The `UFO-PADDING` constant accounts for the two factors I described above and is used to place the `UFO` on the scene. Thus, I expect the UFO to stop when it barely touches the surface of the `FLATBED-ROCK`. But it does not! Is there any other factor that affects the ordinate of the `UFO`? What am I missing?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I believe the issue is because when you do:

```
(define UFO-PADDING
   (- SCENE-HEIGHT 
      (/ (image-height UFO) 2)
      (image-height FLAT-ROCKBED)))
```

What you're doing is saying the padding of the *center* of the UFO is the HEIGHT - (image-height UFO / 2) - the image-height FLAT-ROCKBED. I believe that you should also do:

```
(/ (image-height FLAT-ROCKBED) 2)
```

Otherwise you'd be subtracting too much.

Comment: Thanks, I don't have access to the PC right now. I will try your advice tomorrow and report.

Comment: I selected your answer as the correct one because it worked. However I didn't understand why it worked.

But since it worked against my calculations I was certain that there was something I did not code correctly. And I found it - when defining the MTSCN I should have offset the placement of the FLAT-ROCKBED but I didn't. That was the main culprit.

Thanks anyways!

Answer (score 1):

The construct animate calls `ufo-landing` with numbers 0, 1, 2, ...
You can try this expression in the interaction window (the repl) to
see the end image.

(ufo-landing 1000)

With a height of say 1000, `ufo-landing` uses this clause:

```
[[> height UFO-PADDING]
 (place-image UFO X-POS UFO-PADDING MTSCN)]]]
```

The y-coordinate is `UFO-PADDING` .
To move the end position of the ufo adjust `UFO-PADDING`.

```
(define UFO-PADDING
  (+  ?
     (- SCENE-HEIGHT 
        (/ (image-height UFO) 2)
        (image-height FLAT-ROCKBED))))
```

Try different numbers at the spot marked with the question mark.

Comment: Thank you for answering. I wasn't clear about what exactly I am struggling with. I have edited the question and added more information. Could you see it again?